# cannot create list item error: Throttled:Query exceeds lookup column threshold.

Tags: infopath, forms-services

This doesn't happen for me (I'm admin) but it does happen for one of my hierarchy owners. He tries to create a form and gets an error, the log shows Throttled:Query exceeds lookup column threshold.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a lookup field on the form?  Does the source list have a lot of items?

Comment: yes I have several lookup fields. how can I increase the limit?

Comment: Monica has provided an answer for you below using PowerShell - though I would suggest you reconsider your solution to see if it can be done a different way - maybe use term sets for some of the columns?   The maximum number of lookup columns is 8 by default - more than that and you are likely to experience performance issues.

Comment: I've taken out the lookups and still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entire script will be : 
***Replace the web url and list name***

```
Add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb http://whateverWeb
$list = $web.Lists[“List Title”]
$list.enablethrottling = $false
$list.update()
Remove-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
```

Answer (score 1):

Central Administration --> Manage Web Application --> Select Web Application --> (Ribbon )General Settings --> (Drop down) Resource Throttling -->List View Lookup Threshold  --> increase value to higher number.

You can also disable throttling settings for a particular list :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://whateverWeb
$list = $web.Lists[“List Title”]
$list.enablethrottling = $false
$list.update()
```

Comment: um....I don't know how to run that.  I added all lines to notepad and saved as ps1 and then ran that from powershell but it didn't run...

Comment: first replace the url of your site with http://whateverWeb

Comment: secondly add following line for execution of powershell

Comment: secondly add following line for execution of powershell  - add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell. Run with adminstrator

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set the Web Application properties in PowerShell:

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication http://whateverApp;
$app.MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation = 500000;
$app.MaxItemsPerThrottledOperationOverride = 500000;
$app.MaxQueryLookupFields = 15;
$app.Update();
```