# too many lookup fields in the Rest API URL exceed the size limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, error

I have too many lookup fields which are like 40+. Using the URL format below exceeds the URL limit which I believe it is 2084.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DepartmentWing')/Items?$select= ../Id,../Title&$expand=../Id,...
```

Any idea how to retrieve the items with the fields being extended so I can get other properties beside Id?

Comment: Try new API i.e. [RenderListDataAsStream](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303858/too-many-lookup-fields-in-the-rest-api-url-exceed-the-size-limit) which can give details without expand. I am not sure whether it will throw any lookup threshold error or not

Comment: I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below suggestions to reduce the number of characters in URL endpoint:

1. Use `LookupColumnId` instead of `LookupColumn/Id` in the `$select` query.
2. Use only `LookupColumn` instead of `LookupColumn/Id` in the `$expand` query.

For example:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('DepartmentWing')/Items?$select=LookupColumn1Id,LookupColumn2Id,LookupColumn1/Title,LookupColumn2/Title&$expand=LookupColumn1,LookupColumn2
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it does not reduce it much. 
My idiot colleague did not care much about the internal names of the fields and now they are way too long and contain spaces and other characters in. By removing them could have saved a lot of chars

Comment: You're welcome, for 40 fields it reduces up to 160 characters. I don't think you will be able to reduce it further. Try to avoid using fields in `$select` query which you are not going to use in your application. and you are right about internal names should have planned properly when fields were initially created in list. It would have reduced the length of internal names.

Comment: $select contains the required fields. I thought of using two separate calls by splitting the fields in half and then merge the data, or another possibility could be batch call, but never tried this one.

Comment: Also, creating 40+ lookup columns in single list is not best practice as displaying 12 or more columns of the following types can cause a list view threshold error: people, lookup, and managed metadata. Refer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285547/sharepoint-online-limitations-for-a-lookup-column-with-multiple-values

Comment: columns are already created and I cannot do anything about it unless I restructure everything. This is the reason of when you have shitty romanian colleauges.